# jquery multiple elements fade in and out cycle

Tags: html, jquery, css

Hello I have created 3 element with IDs (rt-1, rt-2, rt-3)

```
<div class="body-wd06as">
<p>Free<span id="rt-1" style="color: #FE2C55;">views</span>
<span id="rt-2" style="color: #FE2C55;">followers</span>
<span id="rt-3" style="color: #FE2C55;">likes</span>
</p>
</div>
```

I want to make it that it would continuously make the one element to fade out and another to fade in(rt-1 element fades in, fades out, rt-2 element fades in, fades out, rt-3 element fades in, fades out then rt-1 element fades in again...& the cycle continues.)

I made that initially these 3 elements are not visible with css:

```
#rt-1{
  display: none;
}

#rt-2{
  display: none;
}

#rt-3{
  display: none;
}
```

jquery code:

```
  $(function ()
  {
      var $element1 = $('#rt-1');
      var $element2 = $('#rt-2');
      var $element3 = $('#rt-3');
      setInterval(function () {
          $element1.fadeOut(1000);
          $element2.fadeIn(1000);
          $element2.fadeOut(1000);
          $element3.fadeIn(1000);
          $element3.fadeOut(1000);
          $element1.fadeIn(1000);

      }, 0);
  });
```

But it doesn't work as intended

Comment: How should it work, when you are triggering fadeOut and fadeIn for all those elements at the exact same time and with the exact same duration …?

Comment: Interval of zero in setInterval() doesn't make sense either

Comment: You have to make display block, try like $element1.show().fadeIn(1000); or $element1.hide().fadeOut(1000); accordingly

Comment: @charlietfl I set interval of zero because I want it to start instantly when website loads

Comment: @HareshMakwana That is not how those methods work. Calling show() and hide() will defeat the purpose of using them. They will manage the `display` internally

Comment: Suggest you read up on how setInterval works. It runs continuously and using zero as delay will cause it to run many many times a second

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You don't need `setInterval` in this at all.
according to [docs](https://api.jquery.com/fadein/) `fadeIn()` and `fadeOut()` takes function as second parameter in which you can invoke another step.

For example:

```js
$(() => {
    const $element1 = $('#rt-1');
    const $element2 = $('#rt-2');
    const $element3 = $('#rt-3');

    let step = -1;

    const fadeAnimate = () => {
        step = (step >= 5) ? 0 : (step + 1);
        switch (step) {
            case 0: $element1.fadeIn(1000, fadeAnimate); break;
            case 1: $element1.fadeOut(1000, fadeAnimate); break;
            case 2: $element2.fadeIn(1000, fadeAnimate); break;
            case 3: $element2.fadeOut(1000, fadeAnimate); break;
            case 4: $element3.fadeIn(1000, fadeAnimate); break;
            case 5: $element3.fadeOut(1000, fadeAnimate); break;
        }
    };

    fadeAnimate();

});
```

```css
.rt {
    display: none;
    color: #FE2C55;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="body-wd06as">
    <p>
        Free
        <span id="rt-1" class="rt">views</span>
        <span id="rt-2" class="rt">followers</span>
        <span id="rt-3" class="rt">likes</span>
    </p>
</div>
```